# Save user info on Android 10 without any permission

Tags: android

There is a question I have no idea. I play a game named 'Solitaire: Fishing Go'(targetSdkVersion:31).

When I uninstalled the game and reinstalled, it automatically restored my game history,
but I didn't create an account for it before and the most important thing is that the game doesn't need any permissions.

I test it on Android 10 and above, on Android 11 and 12, I can create a custom folder in an external public dir (such as Documents dir) and name it with the user id, and then when I reinstall the App I can get the user id through the custom folder name, but I can't do this on Android 10, because I don't have any permissions.

So I want to know how to implement this functionality on my own Android app on Android 10 or even below Android 10

The most important thing is 'Solitaire: Fishing Go' doesn't need any
permissions on Android 10 too

Comment: `but I can't do this on Android 10, because I don't have any permissions.` Well get those permissions!

Comment: How will you get an user id if you don't create an account? If you are signing up with google or Facebook then also you are creating an account in their platform

Comment: I want to know how to do this without any permissions, I can get a user id from the server first, and how can I keep it when I reinstall the app